# Asymptotic lower bound of O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, lower-bound

Are there problems in P that have a proven asymptotic lower bound of O(n^2) or higher? (n is the number of bits a problem instance can be represented by). This is not a homework question, just curiosity.

Comment: Not really a programming question...

Comment: In P? What's P? And yes, there are, for example bubble sort is `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: @H2CO3 (1) [P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%28complexity%29) as in "P=NP?" I suppose. (2) Please don't confuse problems and algorithms.

Comment: @H2CO3- The question asks whether there are problems that *require* quadratic time to solve, rather than whether there are *algorithms* that require quadratic time to finish.  It's much harder to show that a problem can't be solved in subquadratic time.

Comment: @delnan Algorithms are ways to decide problems. It's just a different perspective.

Comment: @G.Bach Exactly, they are closely related but not the same thing. As templatetypedef explained above, the complexity of a problem is not necessary the complexity of one particular algorithm that solves that problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the [time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) implies the existence of such problems. They're arguably not natural because they involve diagonalizing over all O(n^2)-time algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

[3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) comes to mind.  There's a [quadratic lower bound known](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/1999/8/contents.html) for a certain linear decision-tree model due to Jeff Erickson.  (There are some barely-subquadratic algorithms for 3SUM in the literature for various models of computation.  But I haven't looked at them and I don't know how they work.)